# Notification is not showing properly

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an chat app. When the app is running notifications are showing correctly. But when it is closed nothing is shown as notification. I have this problem while testing it in real mobiles ( Honor ). I gave all the permissions and receiver action in manifest. I could not understand what is stopping its behavior. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.android.chatappsocket.Notifier">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Service.java

```
Intent i=new Intent(xxx.this,yyy.class);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: Without any code you question is senseless.

Comment: Send snippet of code. difficult to understand you problem without code.

Comment: You are using GCM Notification?

Comment: No am using php service to check for new message.

Comment: and I got this when app closes. ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy

Comment: What kind of `Service` do you use? and where is the `braodcastreceiver` defined?